# React CSS Translate Transition not working

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I am trying to animate a side menu, but for some reason it just wont work!

I read on a few answers that using a map to map the `<li>` items could be the issue (and I have tried with just a few items with static text), but that doesnt seem to be the problem.

Additionally, I have also put the generated items into a state, and wrapped the set with an useEffect to prevent retriggering of the map, still doesn't work. Only the transition is not working, the menu is appearing where it must appear, closes itself when I click the menu button, etc.

**EDIT**: I think it is worth mentioning that while working on it on my development server, when I am updating my css file (its not refreshing the page), when I change some of the styles that make the sidebar move, it moves with animation, so the animation is there, it is just not working when I am clicking the open/close button but it just appears instantly.

P.S. `uuid()` generates unique key for each element, so that is not an issue either.

```
export default function SideBar({ names, closeSidebarOnClick, show }) {
  const [robots, setRobots] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setRobots(GenerateNavItems());
  }, names);

  function GenerateNavItems() {
    return names.map((robotName) => {
      return (
        <li key={uuid()} className={`nav-item`} onClick={() => {closeSidebarOnClick();}}>
          {robotName}
        </li>
      );
    });
  }
      
  return (
    <nav className={`sidebar ${show ? "show-sidebar" : ""}`}>
      <ul>{robots}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

```css
.nav-item {
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-sidebar-button {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 300;
  /* z-index: 50; */
}

.toggle-sidebar-button:active {
  border: none;
}

.toggle-sidebar-button-line {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.sidebar.show-sidebar {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.sidebar ul {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="content row">
    <div class="toggle-sidebar-button">
      <div class="toggle-sidebar-button-line"></div>
      <div class="toggle-sidebar-button-line"></div>
      <div class="toggle-sidebar-button-line"></div>
    </div>
    <nav class="sidebar ">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">ROBOT 1</li>
        <li class="nav-item">ROBOT 2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="rendered-robot col">
      <div>CHOOSE ROBOT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include a stack snippet example with the rendered html and css?

Comment: Im not exactly sure what you mean? You want to see the html tree?

Comment: tried `transform: translateX(-100px);` I mean dont use % rather use px

Comment: @Sean I have added the snippet

Comment: @Ishank just tried it, doesnt work

Comment: You're sure `show` ever gets changed?

Comment: It's possible that as you are re-rendering the nav component so the transition is not been visible. I suggest you to try this experiment - In `closeSidebarOnClick`dont let this do a re-render and just use the  -  `document.getElementsByTagName('nav').classList.add('show-sidebar');` let me know if that shows the animation?

Comment: @Mordechai yes of course, it is opening the Sidebar, its just that its not animating it.

Comment: @Ishank TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined, it doesnt find it by tag nav

Comment: oops this - `document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].classList.add('show-sidebar');`

Comment: A codesandbox would be very helpful

Comment: @Ishank I added an id and found it by ID, it did show the sidebar WITH animation.

Comment: ok then the re-rendering is something you need to do something about

Comment: Okay, I see where this is headed, the function that is handling the state is actually in my App component, so parent of the Sidebar, so it is actually rerendering the app component, so I have to move that out of there somehow and either put it in the sidebar or not use state at all and just add/remove the class... but wouldnt it be a bad practice to do it like that with the getElementBy.... ?

Comment: P.S. Add this as an answer so that I can accept it, its obvious what the problem is now :)

Comment: well, it may be a bad practice but when it comes to css animations what is the alternative we have? I use this via redux all the time :) I think the dom must not be used directly frequently but since this is a nav bar and likely there is only one nav in the entire app, this is much shall be ok. Let me know in case you find a typical react way of getting css animations

Comment: @Darkbound we can use `React.createRef()` instead of doing a DOM query

Comment: I tried to build a sample of your code and the menu works fine,
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-johnson-hxz35?file=/src/App.js
am i missing something? "click precisely on the text "choose robot"

Comment: @Menawer missing styles.css

Comment: i moved all the css to App.css :P that shouldn't be an issue,try now

Comment: Well on my side css is missing from App too and the Container component is empty, maybe I need a new link, and the one above is outdated?

Comment: Really sorry about that, 
https://codesandbox.io/s/hxz35 , hope this works for you :D

Comment: Well the first time I opened it and clicked on the menu it worked and then it stopped working. Anyway, the architecture is very different from mine, inside the App.js I have the state that controls it and then I have SidebarToggleButton (the hamburger icon) and the Sidebar itself both of which are updating the state function which is in App.js. And the Container that you created, I have no idea what that is, it is returning another navbar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219568/discussion-between-menawer-and-darkbound).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that as you are re-rendering the nav component so the transition is not been visible. I suggest you to try this experiment - In `closeSidebarOnClickdont` don't let this do a re-render and just use the - `document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].classList.add('show-sidebar');`

There is a way to create a `React.createRef()` or `useRef` as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) but this again is not to be used frequently.

Well, it may be a bad practice but when it comes to css animations what is the alternative we have? I use these animations via redux all the time :) I think the dom must not be manipulated directly frequently but since this is a nav bar and likely there is only one nav in the entire app, this much shall be ok. Let me know in case you find a typical react way of getting css animations work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, and uuid() WAS the problem. Simply using a different type of key solved the transition issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).